# Customize pgf-umlsd call bar background color

Tags: pgf-umlsd

I'm trying to recreate the following sequence diagram with `pgf-umlsd`:

[image: sequence diagram]

I'm interested how can I change the background color of call bars.

Here's what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread{browser}{Browser}{}
        \newinst[1]{web}{Web process}{}
        \newinst[1]{ext}{External service}{}

        \begin{call}{browser}{HTTP request}{web}{HTTP response}
            \begin{call}{web}{Fetch RSS}{ext}{}
                \begin{call}{ext}{\color{red}!! Not responsive !!}{ext}{}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end{call}

    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: sequence diagram with pgf-umlsd]

Comment: All the bars, or individual bars? The optional argument to `\newthread` defines the color of the bars in that thread, e.g. `\newthread[blue!30!red]{browser}{Browser}{}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! I'm aware of the argument to `\newthread`. I'm interested in the styling of individual bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the bars in a thread can be changed by using the optional argument to `\newthread`. For example if you change your code to

```
\newthread[blue]{browser}{Browser}{}
```

all the bars become blue instead of gray.

But you can also have different colours. The bars are drawn with `\draw [threadstyle] ...`, so you can simply redefine `threadstyle` along the way, with e.g. `\tikzset{threadstyle/.style={fill=cyan}}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread[blue!50!red]{browser}{Browser}{}
        \newinst[1]{web}{Web process}{}
        \newinst[1]{ext}{External service}{}
        \begin{call}{browser}{HTTP request}{web}{HTTP response}
            \tikzset{threadstyle/.style={top color=white,bottom color=red}}
            \begin{call}{web}{Fetch RSS}{ext}{}
                \tikzset{threadstyle/.style={fill=cyan}}
                \begin{call}{ext}{\color{red}!! Not responsive !!}{ext}{}
                    \tikzset{threadstyle/.style={fill=red}}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end{call}

    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For one bar with red shading:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread[white]{browser}{Browser}{}
        \newinst[1]{web}{Web process}{}
        \newinst[1]{ext}{External service}{}
        \begin{call}{browser}{HTTP request}{web}{HTTP response}
            \tikzset{threadstyle/.style={top color=white,bottom color=red}}
            \begin{call}{web}{Fetch RSS}{ext}{}
                \tikzset{threadstyle/.style={fill=white}}
                \begin{call}{ext}{\color{red}!! Not responsive !!}{ext}{}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end{call}

    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```